# Como ejecutar código PHP sin necesidad de abrir la pagina donde se encuentra? (Webhooks MercadoPago)

Tags: php, html, mercadopago, webhook, checkout

Tengo una pagina de ventas online, en la cual por método de pago tengo integrado el checkout pro de MercadoPago, luego de que el usuario realice su pago necesito comprobar es status del mismo, para saber si sigue pendiente, fue rechazado o ya fue acreditado, tengo entendido que mediante las Webhooks puedes pedir información sobre el pago realizado, especificando un enlace a donde se te envié dicha información (`notification_url`) [Webhooks MercadoPago](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/guides/notifications/webhooks) Ahora pongo un ejemplo para que se entienda lo que necesito hacer:
Supongamos que especifique como `notification_url` la siguiente url: `https://mipagina/notifications` al momento en el que me llegue la información a esa url, necesito ejecutar código PHP sin necesidad de abrir la pagina físicamente, tendría que suceder todo automático al mismo tiempo, se realiza la solicitud de pago, mercadopago me notifica enviando la información a `https://mipagina/notifications`, cuando llega la información automáticamente vincula los datos que llegaron con los datos de mi ultima venta

ACTUALIZO CON UNA NUEVA DUDA Y POSIBLE SOLUCION:
yo establezco mi `notification_url`, una vez haya información de pago, al instante MercadoPago me envía una notificación a esa url... el código que yo tenga escrito allí, se ejecuta cuando recibo la información?

Comment: Podrías hacerlo mediante [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) o mediante la [nueva API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: Si, se ejecutará el código. Si te fijas puedes configurar una url al hacer la petición, por lo que puedes generar una url personalizada por usuario al realizar la petición, de esta forma te aseguras de que los atacantes lo tengan más complicado

Comment: Vaya, genial, me estaba comiendo la cabeza intentando saber si se ejecutaba el código o no, hasta ahora venia haciendo todo en localhost... Gracias por el consejo sobre la url personalizada, lo hare de esa manera. @ICIM

Comment: De nada @fran-schiavone Cualquier cosa ya sabés...